# Redis store lists of values inside Redis hash

Tags: redis

My task is to get the list of animals (for example) for a specific user_id.

I don't want to use set/list for each user.

I have tried to use hash where each field is a user_id and each value is a concatenated string of animals. For example: `{"1234" : "dog cat", "8477" : "bird dog"}`. Here, I can get the animals for user "1234", with just one call to Redis.

I know there is an [APPEND](https://redis.io/commands/append) command, that appends items to a string. But this is not working for appending to value inside a hash.

I have also tried to use set, and get the values by prefix. For the example above, my set would contain: `("1234:dog", "1234:cat", "8477:bird", "8477:dog")`. In order to get all animals for user "1234", I need to search for prefix "1234:". But this is not scale when I have too many items.

What can I do in order to complete my task?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you do not want to keep a separate Set/List for every user but want to get data for each user in optimal way, Redis SortedSet data structure and lexicographical search seems to be your solution.

Keep data in a SortedSet (named `animals`):

```
ZADD animals 0 1234:dog 0 1234:cat 0 8477:bird 0 8477:dog
```

Get data of user `1234` from that SortedSet:

```
ZRANGEBYLEX animals [1234: (1234;
```

Output:

```
1) "1234:cat"
2) "1234:dog"
```

Comment: @sazzad i coundnt find the max number of keys that one sorted set can hold. do you know it?

Comment: @EyalCh Do you know the same for a Set/List/Hash?

Answer (score 4):

> Redis' data structures cannot be nested inside other data structures, so storing a List inside a Hash is not possible.

In redis, you are free to create as many keys as you want. So what you can do is to make keys appending **`user_id` and `<hash_key>`**. Maintain a hashSet/list for that key. For example:

```
user_id:1234 =["dog", "cat"];
user_id:8477 =["bird", "dog"];
```

Check out the following links for more details:

1. [redis-storing-list-inside-hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203717/redis-storing-list-inside-hash)
2. [writing-a-query-to-add-multiple-values-to-a-key-in-redis-hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864968/writing-a-query-to-add-multiple-values-to-a-key-in-redis-hashes)

Comment: as i said, i want to avoid to save a key for each user

Answer (score 0):

In fact @ruhul's answer is a good solution. However, if you insist on saving all users' info in a single key, you can try the following solution.

Save the information in a `HASH` as you've tried. When you need to append a new animal to a given user. You can use `HGET` command to get the animals he already has. Then add the new animal to the string, and use the `HSET` command to update his animal info.

In order to make it atomic, you can wrap this logic into a [Lua scripting](https://redis.io/commands/eval).